# Extract mass-orthogonal eigenvectors from the solution of standard eigenvalue problem

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let us take the solution of the generalized eigenvalue problem, $(A - \lambda * B) * v = 0$, obtained from the standard eigenvalue problem, $(\frac{1}{\lambda}  \ I - A^{-1} * B) * w = 0$. So $\lambda$ and $w$  are known. Not all of them, I am thinking of a large pencil, $A$ and $B$ being real, large, sparse, symmetric, positive definite. So, the number of eigenvalues obtained is $M<<$ dimensions of $A, B$.

The eigenvectors $w$ are not $B$-orthogonal. Is there an inexpensive way of converting the $w$'s to the $v$'s (which are $B$-orthogonal)? That is

$(ith-v)^T * B * (jth-v) = \delta_{ij}$, for all $1 \le  i, j \le M$.

By the way, I am aware of an algorithm, but it requires the solution of another, dense, standard eigenvalue problem of dimension $M$. My question is whether there is a less expensive approach.